# Align image button not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a table. My problem is that the two image buttons should be aligned. The problem is that whatever I try the second image is always under the first image. I want the two images to be aligned horizontally.

This is my code for the table:

```
public function dataview($query)
{
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();

  if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
  {
    while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo($row['user_id']); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo($row['username']); ?></td>
          <td><?php echo($row['password']); ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="edit.php?user_id=<?php echo ($row['user_id']); ?>"><input name="image" type="image" value="edit"><img src="image/EDIT.png" class="img-responsive" width="30px"></a>
            <a href="delete.php?user_id=<?php echo ($row['user_id']); ?>"><input name="image" type="image" value="delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"><img src="image/DELETE.png" class="img-responsive" width="30px"></a>
          </td>
          <!--<td><a href="DELITEM.PHP?user_id=<?php echo ($row['user_id']); ?>" <img src="image/DELETE.png" width="25" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');">Delete</a></td>-->

        </tr>
      <?php
    }
  }
  else
  {
    ?>
      <tr>
        <td>Nothing here...</td>
      </tr>
    <?php
  }

}

?>
```

Comment: have you tried reducing image width and increasing the width of the respective td

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give float style as left for both anchor tags. Make sure that there is enogh space in the td to fit these two images.

```
 <a style="float:left" href="edit.php?user_id=<?php echo ($row['user_id']); ?>"<input name="image" type="image" value="edit"><image src="image/EDIT.png" class="img-responsive" width="30px"></a>

 <a style="float:left" href="delete.php?user_id=<?php echo ($row['user_id']); ?>"<input name="image" type="image" value="delete" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?');"><image src="image/DELETE.png" class="img-responsive" width="30px"></a>
```

Comment: can i ask one more thing?